# [BEGINNER]set up a loop in switch default

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

As my first little project, I'm trying to set up a quiz. I wrote the method to generate questions and answers. I'm now trying to force the user to enter either 1 or 2 to continue and loop while he does not.
I'm kinda lost at this point. Am I missing something really obvious?

```
public static boolean generateQuestion2(String question, String answer1, String answer2) {
    boolean bingo;
    System.out.println(question);
    System.out.println("(1) " + answer1);
    System.out.println("(2) " + answer2); //bingo

    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int antwort = scan1.nextInt();

    switch (antwort) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Falsch...");
            return bingo = false;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Richtig!");
            return bingo = true;

        default:
            // Here I intend to loop while antwort != 1 and 2
            while (antwort != 1 && antwort != 2) {
                System.out.println(" Bitte 1 doer 2 eintippen");
                return bingo = false;
            }
            return bingo = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: the while you wrote is irrelevant. the while should contain the nextInt() and the whole switch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(generateQuestion2("x", "y", "z"));
    }

    public static boolean generateQuestion2(String question, String answer1, String answer2) {
        boolean bingo = false;
        boolean valid = true;
        System.out.println(question);
        System.out.println("(1) " + answer1);
        System.out.println("(2) " + answer2); // bingo

        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int antwort = scan1.nextInt();
        do {
            valid = true;
            switch (antwort) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Falsch...");
                bingo = false;
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Richtig!");
                bingo = true;
                break;
            default:
                valid = false;
                System.out.println(" Bitte 1 doer 2 eintippen");
                antwort = scan1.nextInt();
            }
        } while (!valid);
        return bingo;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
x
(1) y
(2) z
4
 Bitte 1 doer 2 eintippen
3
 Bitte 1 doer 2 eintippen
2
Richtig!
true
```

**Another sample run:**

```
x
(1) y
(2) z
4
 Bitte 1 doer 2 eintippen
3
 Bitte 1 doer 2 eintippen
1
Falsch...
false
```

**Another sample run:**

```
x
(1) y
(2) z
1
Falsch...
false
```

**Another sample run:**

```
x
(1) y
(2) z
2
Richtig!
true
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the loop to modify `antwort`, you need to re-read it from `scan1`.

Also, you unconditionally return from the function inside the function. This will *immediately* return.

And the loop should probably be round the whole `switch`.

Lastly, for only two values, I would rather use a simple `if ... else if`.

Comment: Yeah, thought about using if ... else, but potentially I want to have up to four answer options, a switch seemed to have more potential to grow.

Comment: @Buddy Then a `switch` make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You return in your loop, so you will exit the method and the loop will stop. 
What you want in that loop is to wait for user-input `int antwort = scan1.nextInt();`. When input is recieved, you want to get back to your switch.

Something like this...

```
// here we wait for input
int antwort = scan1.nextInt();
while (true) {
  if (antwort == 1 || antwordt == 2) {
    return processAntwort(antwort);
  } else {
    System.out.println(" Bitte 1 doer 2 eintippen");
    // here again we wait for input
    antwort = scan1.nextInt();
  }
}
private boolean processAntwort(int antwort) {
  return antwort == 2;
}
```